# Defusing fork bomb: kill forking processes

Tags: linux, bash, docker

I want to execute user-provided (potentially unsafe) code in shell using docker. Every run should be limited by time, say, 10 seconds. So after 10 seconds I want to stop the command and all the forks made by it.

I've set up appropriate limit of max number of processes using `ulimit -u 30` and now forkbomb doesn't made any damage to the system.

I run docker by user with id=1000, user inside container will have id=3000, so user who starts the command doesn't blocked by the fork bomb.

Now I want to deal with timeout. Unfortunately, `timeout 10s docker run -u 3000 ... forkbomb` doesn't work. What I have to do is to kill all the processes owned by the user with id=3000, but these processes fork infinitely and I'm worried that `killall -KILL -u 3000` won't always work. `killall` isn't atomic, is it?

So, I'm looking for a way to kill all the processes owned by some specific user even if the processes fork. I found a [blog post](http://blog.infizeal.com/2013/04/defusing-fork-bomb.html) which have following code:

```
cd /proc;
for p in [0-9]*; do read CMDLINE < $p/cmdline; if [[ $CMDLINE == "processWithBombName" ]]; 
then kill -s SIGSTOP $p; fi; done
for p in [0-9]*; do read CMDLINE < $p/cmdline; if [[ $CMDLINE == "processWithBombName" ]]; 
then kill -s SIGKILL $p; fi; done
```

First, it the code above doesn't have concurrency issues? For example, while we do stop, the loop read processes with id={1, 2, 3} and while it's stopping pid=1, the process with id 2 has died and pid=4 has been created. Will pid=4 be killed?

Second, how can I kill all the processes for the user and be sure that no new processes have been created?

Comment: I might be missing something but why not run each forkbomb inside its own docker container and then kill all docker containers older than 10s using a cron? Killing the container will kill all processes inside it.

Comment: @UsmanIsmail Thank you! It's working. Are there any guarantees about new processes after kill (while docker does kill new processes will appear and will stay forever)?

Comment: As long as all new process were children of the primary docker processes they should all be killed. This is ensured by the kernal see docs here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pid_namespaces.7.html